# cin in my program doesn't work properly. How can I fix it?

Tags: c++, cin

I have some problems with cin. When I enter a character instead of an integer cin doesn't work and after that I can't even enter a new value. What should I do? I have already tried fflush(stdin)

```
struct PersonList
{
    Person person;
    PersonList* personListPtr;
};


void addPerson(PersonList*& ptr, int position);
void deletePersonList(PersonList* ptr);




int main()
{
    PersonList* personListPtr = NULL;

    int flag = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    int i;

    while(flag != 27)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "1 - add objects\n"
            << "2 - delete objects\n"
            << "ESC - exit\n";
        switch(flag)
        {
        case '1':
            cout << "Enter position: ";
            **cin >> pos;**
            addPerson(personListPtr, pos);
            break;
        case '2':
            break;
        case '3':
            break;
        }
        flag = _getch();
    }


    deletePersonList(personListPtr);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you should be taking input before the `switch` statement but aren't. How does your application know which menu option to execute if you don't prompt the user for it?

Comment: He'll fall through the switch unless by chance `flag` contains one of the three characters.  (It's not at all obvious to me what he is trying to do, but I suspect that he needs something like ncurses, and a lot more code, to do it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be mixing several idioms.  I don't know what
`_getch()` does, but I can't imagine that it is in anyway
compatible with `std::cin`; `std::cin` will have (or may have)
read ahead, reading your flag character, for example.  You
cannot simply mix different streams from the same source.

As for the particular problem you describe, once you enter
something which can't be converted into what you are reading,
the stream goes into an error state (which you should check
before using the value), and all operations on it become no-ops
until you clear the error (`std::istream::clear()`).  But that's
not going to fix the other problems.  If you insist on using
something like `_getch()`, then you'll have to use it for all of
your input, building up a string for input of the position, and
using `std::istringstream` to convert it.  Depending on what the
function actually does, you may also have to deal with things
like backspace, enter and maybe even echoing.